# Migrating Wordpress legacy app to RoR with Devise. Password hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, devise, passwords, legacy-database

I have a database with hundreds of users on an old Wordpress application that I want to migrate to a new RoR application. I am stuck with the passwords. Wordpress has a different encryption than Devise. Its pattern starts with "$P$".
How can I do to create a custom encryptor/digest for my Devise User model to authenticate the old passwords?